# Implementing algebraic data types to my compiler

Tags: haskell, compiler-construction, algebraic-data-types, type-constructor

I've been trying to write a small compiler for the past few weeks, while reading Stephen Diehl's great tutorial "Write You A Haskell". I'm currently writing an interpreter before writing the compiler.

I have troubles to represent my values evaluated from an algebraic data type constructor application (e.g. in Haskell `Just 1`, `Left "error"`, etc...).

My values are currently represented by the following type:

```
data Value
    = Int Integer
    | Flt Double
    | Chr Char
    | Str String
    | Lam Name AST.Expr (Scope Value)
    | HLam (Value -> Value)
```

How would one implement type constructors ?

So far I've thought of this:

```
data Value
    = Int Integer
    | Flt Double
    | Chr Char
    | Str String
    | App Constr [Value]  -- Constr applied of [Value]
    | Lam Name AST.Expr (Scope Value)
    | HLam (Value -> Value)

-- Constructor ID and signature
-- would be translated to a lambda abstraction
data Constr = Constr Name [Type]
```

But I would have to check every time I work with the constructor if the lengths of the signature and the number of applied values are equal.

Is there another solution ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps GADTs can be used. However, even assuming that it is possible to encode this static guarantee in a GADT, I fear the difficulty bar will be raised significantly. I would first solve the exercise with runtime checks, only.

Comment: @chi: Thanks for the advice, but I can't figure out how would you implement that with GADTs, so I can't see how harder this is compared to runtime checking.


edit: Nevermind, I figured out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there are a number of solutions. The fanciest is to use something like [sized-vector](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sized-vector) and [type-natural](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/type-natural-0.3.0.0/docs/Data-Type-Natural.html) to constrain the arity of type constructors and arguments to match. If this approach interests you I would look at the source code of the linked libraries to see how it is done, but it involves a huge number of GHC extensions and quite a bit of work.

A less fancy solution is to use create a family of constructor types and app types, as in.

```
data Const0 
data Const1
-- etc.
data ConstN

data App0 = App0 Const0
data App1 = App1 Const1 Value
-- etc.
data AppN = AppN ConstN Value Value ... Value

data AppI = AppI0 App0 | AppI1 App1 | ... | AppIN App1N
```

This requires producing either manually or automatically quite a bit of noise.

To be frank, I expect the effort of enforcing this invariant in the type level is not worth the benefit. Instead I would suggest using [smart constructors](https://wiki.haskell.org/Smart_constructors) to enforce this at a value level.

Comment: Since I need to use pattern matching on my constructor, I'll try sized vectors. If it is too complicated, I'll go for runtime checking.
Thanks for the answer.
Edit: I could use "getters" to access the values of my App constructor but I find the fancy solution more elegant.